# Using boost::numeric::odeint to integrate a non-linear function f'(x, y, z) = a + b*I

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I would like to integrate a function that maps a 3D point (parametrized by `t`) to a 2D point (complex plane) using an adaptative step scheme. There is no closed-form for the derivative of my function and it is non-linear.

I've tried the following to see if the code would work. It compiles but the result is wrong. The test function being integrated (`t` from `0` to `1`; `i` is the complex number) is

> Exp[ -Norm[ {1.1, 2.4, 3.6}*t ] * i ]

The expected result is

> -0.217141 - 0.279002 i

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
namespace odeint = boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef std::complex<double> state_type;

class Integrand {
    ublas::vector<double> point_;
public:
    Integrand(ublas::vector<double> point){
        point_ = point;
    }
    void operator () (const state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, const double t){
        point_ *= t;
        const std::complex<double> I(0.0, 1.0);
        dxdt = std::exp( -norm_2(point_)*I );
    }
};

std::complex<double> integral(ublas::vector<double> pt) {
    typedef odeint::runge_kutta_cash_karp54< state_type > error_stepper_type;
    double err_abs = 1.0e-10;
    double err_rel = 1.0e-6;
    state_type x = std::complex<double>(1.0, 0.0);
    return odeint::integrate_adaptive(
               odeint::make_controlled<error_stepper_type>(err_abs, err_rel),
               Integrand(pt), x, 0.0, 1.0, 0.001);
}

int main() {
    ublas::vector<double> pt(3);
    pt(0) = 1.1;
    pt(1) = 2.4;
    pt(2) = 3.6;
    std::cout << integral(pt) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code outputs

> 5051 + 0 i

I suspect the problem is in my definition of `x`, the state vector. I don't know what it should be.

Comment: You say that there is no closed form expression for the derivative of your function, yet you then code `dxdt = expr;` - a closed-form expression. Which is it?

Comment: As a side note, it's usually poor form to include a namespace and then include another header file, that's just asking for problems with redefining names. Unless there is a good reason to do so, put all your includes first, and then put all you `using namespace` declarations after.

Comment: @SirGuy the function I coded is just a test funtion, not my actual one which is way bigger and complex with hysteresis phenomena (I can find its derivative numerically only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is because you are modifying `point_` everytime you call `Integrand::operator()`.

Instead of:

```
point_ *= t;
dxdt = exp(-norm_2(point_)*I);
```

You probably meant:

```
dxdt = exp(-norm_2(point_ * t) * I);
```

Your Integrand::operator() should be marked as a const function when you don't member variables to change, that would help catch these errors in the future.

After looking at the docs for odeint, integrate_adaptive returns the number of steps performed.  The input parameter `x` actually holds the final result so you want to do:

```
odeint::integrate_adaptive(
           odeint::make_controlled<error_stepper_type>(err_abs, err_rel),
           Integrand(pt), x, 0.0, 1.0, 0.001);
return x;
```

Running this prints `(0.782859,-0.279002)`, which is still not the answer you're looking for. The answer you're looking for comes as a result of starting `x` at `0` instead of `1`.

```
state_type x = std::complex<double>(0.0, 0.0);
odeint::integrate_adaptive(
           odeint::make_controlled<error_stepper_type>(err_abs, err_rel),
           Integrand(pt), x, 0.0, 1.0, 0.001);
return x;
```

Comment: The `point_` assignment is probably a source of error. Doing as you suggests yields the result `11.0 + 0 i`, still not what is expected.